# C alignment at NOT a power of 2

Tags: c, alignment

In gcc there is a directive called `.align` that allows me to align things at boundaries that need to be a *power of two*. However, on my Intel Core Duo machine I want to align some code (not data) at addresses that are NOT powers of two. Is there any straightforward way to do that?

Because obviously, `.align 3` gives me the error: Error: alignment not a power of two.

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: Why would you possibly want to align to non 2^n boundaries? Did Intel introduce ternary circuits in Core Duo?

Comment: To run some memory tests I need to have proper code alignment ;)

Answer (score 3):

Align to a power of two, and then pad with the appropriate number of assembler NOPs before the code you want to be misaligned. (I'm presuming you know how to do in-line assembler in gcc here; comment if you don't.)

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that. I am aware of this option, however, it would be easier if I could "hard" align it! Thanks

Comment: It would be easier, yes, except it may be a bit much to ask the "align" command to unalign things!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using GCC, you can used packed structures and manual padding:

```
struct very_slow_t
{
   int a;
   char padding;
   int b; /* b is now padded to byte 5 */
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

But why would you possibly want to do that? I mean, it would make your program much slower.

Comment: Thanks, but more looking for code alignment, sorry for not specifically mentioning that!